# Data Binding in axis2

Tags: java, data-binding, web-services, apache-axis, interop

I want to create a simple webservice using Axis2 1.5.1. The expectations from the webservice is:
**1. interoperability

2. interaction with custom objects**

Do i require to use any data binding (initially i thought of using ADB) or is deploying WS using POJO sufficient?
Do we have enough documentation for the Data binding?
Because Axis2 quick start guide has some text for how to create webservices using these data bindings but it doesn't list the scenarios where to use what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Axis databinding (ADB) code cannot be reused as it is only for Axis2 Web services.

Your POJOs should be sufficient for data binding.

Comment: but how can i try changing the wsdl type (doc/literal) when i deploy webservice from POJO beacause the wsdl is autogenerated by giving ?wsdl in servlet